# understanding clicks behaviour

Tags: jquery

I wrote this simple code to understand why if I click the "click me" text for the second time JQuery does not display the "second" text.

```
<div id="clickme">Click me</div>
<div id="sometext">This is text ZERO</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function($) {

        $("#clickme").click(function(){ 
            if (a == 1) {
                $('#sometext').replaceWith('<div id="sometext">This is text TWO</div>');
            }
            else {
                $('#sometext').replaceWith('<div id="sometext">This is text ONE</div>');
                var a = 1;
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

I expected the following behaviour:

1. Page is loaded and the text 'This is text ZERO' is displayed
2. I click the link the first time and JQuery displays 'This is text ONE'
3. I click the link a second time and jQuery displays 'This is text TWO'

Instead point #3 is not processed or at least the text is not displayed. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a scope issue as mentioned above, the variable 'a' must be defined in the scope of the page, not the click event.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    var a = 0;

    $("#clickme").click(function() {
        if (a == 1) {
            $('#sometext').replaceWith('<div id="sometext">This is text TWO</div>');
            a = 0;
        }
        else {
            $('#sometext').replaceWith('<div id="sometext">This is text ONE</div>');
            a = 1;
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d5xSH/

Answer (score 2):

Because `a` is defined locally, it is a scope issue.  Initialize a globally and it will work.  See Below

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
   var a = 0;
   $("#clickme").click(function(){ 
     if (a == 1) {
       $('#sometext').replaceWith('<div id="sometext">This is text TWO</div>');
     }
     else {
       $('#sometext').replaceWith('<div id="sometext">This is text ONE</div>');
       a = 1;
     }
   });
});
```

Here is a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jfhartsock/Khp7P/1/

Comment: I'd suggest not making the variable globally scoped though.  Especially with such an ambiguous name as "a", you're likely to conflict with some other code on your page.  moving var a=0 just inside the .ready callback should work for you and keep a encapsulated locally.